# How to Add a viewModel to a core block?

Tags: magento2, layout, dependency-injection, di, viewmodel

I am trying to overwrite a core template and add my custom logic using a viewModel as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="name.of.the.core.block" template="Vendor_CustomModule::path/to/template.phtml">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Vendor\CustomModule\ViewModel\Class</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

But it's not working.

I know it is possible to inject viewModels into blocks but not sure if it is possible by referencing an existing block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible and it works as expected!

The reason why it was not working was because I was not implementing the right interface in my **viewModel** class.

All **viewModels** need to to implement `ArgumentInterface`.

```
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\ViewModel;

class Class implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear what's your question and what you're trying to do by `<arguments>` element. But I can say you can't use "`template`" attribute inside the "`<referenceBlock>`" element as it's invalid.

Maybe you can redefine the core block with the same name.

Comment: Hi, yes you can. In fact, it is one of the two ways (and I think the only that works) you can use to replace a block template using layout. You can read more about it here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template

Comment: But the question is about viewModel and the possibility to inject them in a core block to modify the blocks template.