# Get front-end customer admin navigation

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend

I'm a beginner in Magento and I try to create a page on which I get all orders of a customer payed with a custom payment method.

Now, the page work but I want the page to looks like a real customer admin page, and to display the navigation on the left.

My custom layout (devis_index_index.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Opsone\KgAdmin\Block\Index" name="devis_index_index" template="Opsone_KgAdmin::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

and my template (index.phtml)

```
<?php $items = $this->getOrderCollection(); ?>

<div class="o-main-box">
    <?php if ($items != 'disconnect' && count($items)): ?>
        <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
            <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
                <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Devis #') ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                        <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Total du devis') ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($items as $_order) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                                <a href="<?= $block->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $_order->getRealOrderId()]); ?>" class="action view">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Voir le devis') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php elseif ($items != 'disconnect' && !count($items)) : ?>
        <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Vous n\'avez aucun devis en cours') ?></span></div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Merci de vous connecter pour accéder à vos devis') ?></span></div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

[image: The navigation I try to display]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `devis_index_index.xml` change content to following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Opsone\KgAdmin\Block\Index" name="devis_index_index" template="Opsone_KgAdmin::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

so remove `layout="1column"` and add `<update handle="customer_account"/>`.

Also as good practice, consider removing your custom block `Opsone\KgAdmin\Block\Index`, and instead move functionalities included inside to View Model like in [Magento 2: How to Add a viewModel to a core block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227725/magento-2-how-to-add-a-viewmodel-to-a-core-block) - you can do same with your own when adding block. Then you will have to add `view_model` as argument to your block and remove `class="Opsone\KgAdmin\Block\Index"` also.

Best regards and good luck :)